# Blender Refraction BSDF too dark

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, shaders, transparency, fire

as you can see in the first picture if i use an refraction shader on a plane in front of the fire/persons it´s way darker then without. I want to use it for an heat distortion because of the fire. I have already increased all the maximum light bounces in the render settings to a very high number but no improvement/change. Am I doing anything wrong here? I use Cycles. Thanks!

[image]
[image]

Comment: Yeah, I’ve encountered to this too. I think it’s just a limitation of cycles. Hopefully, in cycles X, they might add some sort of booster that makes light inherently try a bit harder when it’s going through refraction. Maybe you could try to implement this with shaders by having the light sources respond to refraction rays with brighter light?

Comment: Hmm yeah too bad. Could you maybe give me an example of how to do it with shaders?
 I don't understand exactly how do you mean it 

Comment: the light’s material, Light Path info, Is Transmission Ray, map range from 0-1 to maybe 1-1.3 Not sure that this would work…

Comment: Hmm i don´t get it. Then I'll probably do it without it first.